# Help with Complicated SQL Alchemy Join

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

First, the database overview:

- `competitors` - people who compete
- `competitions` - things that people compete at
- `competition_registrations` - Competitors registered for a particular competition
- `event` - An "event" at a competition.
- `events_couples` - A couple (2 competitors) competing in an event.

First, `EventCouple`, a Python class corresponding to `events_couples`, is:

```
class EventCouple(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'events_couples'

    competition_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('competitions.id'), primary_key=True)
    event_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('events.id'), primary_key=True)

    leader_id = Column(Integer)
    follower_id = Column(Integer)

    __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint(['competition_id', 'leader_id'], ['competition_registrations.competition_id', 'competition_registrations.competitor_id']),
        ForeignKeyConstraint(['competition_id', 'follower_id'], ['competition_registrations.competition_id', 'competition_registrations.competitor_id']),
        {}
    )
```

I have a Python class, `CompetitorRegistration`, that corresponds to a record/row in `competition_registrations`. A competitor, who is registered, can compete in multiple events,  but either as a "leader", or a "follower". I'd like to add to `CompetitorRegistration` an attribute `leading`, that is a list of `EventCouple` where the `competition_id` and `leader_id` match. This is my `CompetitorRegistration` class, complete with attempt:

```
class CompetitorRegistration(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'competition_registrations'

    competition_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('competitions.id'), primary_key=True)
    competitor_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('competitors.id'), primary_key=True)
        email = Column(String(255))
    affiliation_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('affiliation.id'))
    is_student = Column(Boolean)
    registered_time = Column(DateTime)
    leader_number = Column(Integer)

    leading = relationship('EventCouple', primaryjoin=and_('CompetitorRegistration.competition_id == EventCouple.competition_id', 'CompetitorRegistration.competitor_id == EventCouple.leader_id'))
    following = relationship('EventCouple', primaryjoin='CompetitorRegistration.competition_id == EventCouple.competition_id and CompetitorRegistration.competitor_id == EventCouple.follower_id')
```

However, I get:

```
ArgumentError: Could not determine relationship direction for primaryjoin
condition 'CompetitorRegistration.competition_id == EventCouple.competition_id
AND CompetitorRegistration.competitor_id == EventCouple.leader_id', on
relationship CompetitorRegistration.leading. Ensure that the referencing Column
objects have a ForeignKey present, or are otherwise part of a
ForeignKeyConstraint on their parent Table, or specify the foreign_keys parameter
to this relationship.
```

Thanks for any help, & let me know if more info is needed on the schema.

Also, another attempt of mine is visible in `following` — this did not error, but didn't give correct results either. (It only joined on the `competition_id`, and completely ignored the `follower_id`)

Answer (score 0):

Your `leading`'s condition mixes expression and string to be `eval()`ed. And `following`'s condition mixes Python and SQL operators: `and` in Python is not what you expected here. Below are corrected examples using both variants:

```
leading = relationship('EventCouple', primaryjoin=(
    (competition_id==EventCouple.competition_id) & \
    (competitor_id==EventCouple.leader_id)))

leading = relationship('EventCouple', primaryjoin=and_(
    competition_id==EventCouple.competition_id,
    competitor_id==EventCouple.leader_id))

following = relationship('EventCouple', primaryjoin=\
    '(CompetitorRegistration.competition_id==EventCouple.competition_id) '\
    '& (CompetitorRegistration.competitor_id==EventCouple.follower_id)')
```